# Is it possible to read PC files from a Mac?

Tags: macos, mac

My partner wants to update her PC to MAC ,and we've found the [following product](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B001UGY400?colid=1T8ZDO6FU9KDC&coliid=I1P7TSDLD0KZH0&ref_=wl_it_dp_o_pC_nS_ttl) on Amazon.

I've been told to run windows 32 bit it needs to be on an older mac, will this machine do that? it needs 32 bit because she is a self employed accountant and has to run a particular application in 32 bit.

Also I was told that the MAC can read data on an USB stick if its in FAT32 or XFAT format, plus it can read NTFS but cannot do anything with it including loading the data into an application say word then saving to the MAC hard drive?

Is there anything else I need to know?

Comment: If you run Windows it can read and write NTFS just fine.

Comment: If she *primarily* wants to use her computer for running Windows applications, it makes little sense to buy a Mac. It's certainly possible to use Macs this way, it's just strange.

Comment: That's one slow old Mac, btw - http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-2-duo-2.66-20-inch-aluminum-early-2009-specs.html It can only run 32-bit XP or Win7 from Boot Camp. If running as a Mac, it can't by default write to NTFS, but running Windows it can.

Comment: Please, next time only ask one question per question. Please take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure a 64 bit OS is backwards compatible with 32 bit apps. Regardless, you will be able to virtualise a 32 bit copy of Windows 7 (say, using Parallels), but you won't be able to install it using Bootcamp.

There are a host of differences between Windows and Mac - but it didn't really take me that long to adjust between the platforms.

Comment: In addition, `wine` may help, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

According to [microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384249(v=vs.85).aspx) 64 bit windows is able to run 32 bit windows applications. So there should not be any problems running the 32 bit application under 64 bit windows.

There is a [guide](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204048) on apples support website where you can find out about what versions of windows are compatible with what macs. Most of the newer macs does not support 32 bit windows. However the iMac you linked to should be able to run 32 bit versions of windows 7 according to this [chart](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016).

There should not be any problems reading NTFS formated drives if you install windows on the mac.